# Is there a way to expand upon Quick Info within MS Access VBA for custom functions?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using Ctrl+I on a function helpfully shows input parameters and return type. Does anyone know a way to expand upon this description for custom functions?

Any mechanism will do, doesn't necessarily have to show in the quick info tooltip.

Comment: What does Ctrl+I give you with your function name?  On my system, it displays the function's declaration in a tooltip ... `OnlyDigits(ByVal pInput As String) As String` Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @HansUp Yes I get the same declaration but I was hoping to pad it out a little for some of the more complex functions to give a brief breakdown of steps, usage, included subs, perhaps potential return values etc. Currently using shift+F2 to go to the declaration and review comments when I need to brush up on such a function, just wondered if it could be done without leaving current code position.